# Tracing an event in Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have an HTML5 web-app and "something" attached a click handler to one of my divs.

If I use the Event Listeners tab I can see the click event and all of its properties - but is there any way to break when an event is fired and trace what is executed?  That may give me more information on what attached it.

Answer (score 5):

Disregard, found it:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners

Simply go into Event Listener Breakpoints under the Sources tab and turn on Mouse > click